# Compilation error in deploying a contract on zksync, using deploy zksync

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, compilation

I'm trying to compile the code but I keep getting an error. Here is the hardhat.config.ts code:

```
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";

module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.8",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {},
  },
  defaultNetwork: "zkSyncMainnet",

  networks: {
    zkSyncMainnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-mainnet.zksync.io",
      ethNetwork: "mainnet", // RPC URL of the network (e.g. `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<API_KEY>`)
      zksync: true,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
  },
};
```

Here is the error it gives: The image shows the complete error; a sort of compilation error, and I don't know what causes it. I've tried using different versions of solidity and zksolc but none has worked. The contract compiled once, but that was when I commented out the "import" statements

[image: Error Message]

Comment: An import line was excluded from the post above, I don't know why. 
Here it is: 

import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";

Comment: The three back ticks ``` need to be in their own line.